# Vim で Vdebug (Xdebug) を使用して Vagrant 環境の PHP コードをデバッグしたい

Tags: php, vim, vagrant

Vim で Vdebug (https://github.com/joonty/vdebug) を使用して
Vagrant 環境 (CentOS 6.7) のコード (PHP 5.6.28) をデバッグしたいのですが、
ブラウザでファイルにアクセスして、ブレイクポイントを貼って、Waiting 状態にしていたのですが
接続ができていないようで、何も反応してくれません。

先日まで MAMP を使用していて、その際は Vdebug は使用できていました。

接続確認の方法や、設定を確認できるコマンド、ログなど、
ご教示いただけますと、大変有難いです。

macOS Sierra 10.12 を使用しています。

Vagrantfile の synced_folder 設定は下記のように設定してあります。

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define "c5" do |v1|
    v1.vm.box = "foobar/centos5"
    v1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.101"
    # config.vm.box_check_update = false
    # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  end

  config.vm.define "c6" do |v2|
    v2.vm.box = "foobar/centos6"
    v2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.102"
    # config.vm.box_check_update = false
    v2.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9001, host: 9001
  end

  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  config.vm.synced_folder "/path/to/workspace", "/var/www/html",
      :owner => "vagrant",
      :group => "apache",
      :mount_options => ["dmode=775,fmode=775"]
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "ulimit -n 4048"

end
```

今回は config.vm.define "c6" do |v2| の方で 
Xdebug を動かせればと思っています。 
できれば、両方を Vim 側で一々設定を変えなくても、Xdebug に接続できるようにしたいです。

Vagrant 環境側には Xdebug を

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release
$ sudo rpm -ivh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
$ sudo yum install -y --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 php php-devel php-pear php-pecl-xdebug
```

でインストールして
`/etc/php.ini` は下記のように設定してあります。

```
;[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"

xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.html_errors=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

ホスト OS (Mac) 側の `~/.vimrc` 内の Vdebug の設定は

```
let g:vdebug_features = {
\    'max_children': 128,
\    'max_data': 5000,
\}
let g:vdebug_options = {
\    "port" : 9001,
\    "server" : '127.0.0.1',
\    "timeout" : 20,
\    "on_close" : 'detach',
\    "break_on_open" : 1,
\    "ide_key" : '',
\    "path_maps" : { '/var/www/html/project-name': '/path/to/workspace/project-name' },
\    "debug_window_level" : 0,
\    "debug_file_level" : 0,
\    "debug_file" : "",
\    "watch_window_style" : 'expanded',
\    "marker_default" : '⬦',
\    "marker_closed_tree" : '▸',
\    "marker_open_tree" : '▾'
\}
```

以上です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `上手く動作してくれません。` ←この部分を具体的に書いた方が良いと思います。実際に動かしたコマンドや手順、出力されたエラーメッセージ等追記下さい。

Comment: @h_east さん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。追記させていただきました。ご教示いただけましたらありがたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。